# Link to content inside of a toggle drawer

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tags, anchor, drawer

I have a few toggle drawers that are closed by default (using jQuery to hide), and opened when their title is clicked.

I'd like to add anchors to the content within the div, and I'm trying to find a way to override the jQuery that's causing the drawer to close automatically.

Here's a fiddle that shows the jQuery code I'm using. Any suggestions on how I could make this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/bd1mbu5j/1/

```
$(".toggle_container").hide();
$("h3.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("normal");
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

Comment: So what's not working in the fiddle?

Comment: @j08691 I've updated the fiddle. The anchor link works if that drawer is already expanded, but I need it to expand the drawer if it's not already expanded.